# SCSS @each loop with two variable sets?

Tags: css, sass

Trying SCSS to work with two variable sets, like below, but it keeps returning the crazy sauce below:

```
 $first: first_1 first_2;
 $second: second_1 second_2
 @each $data in $first {
    @each $content in $second {
    .example-class[data-reactid$='#{$data}'] {
        &:before {
          content: '#{$content}';
        }
    }

}
```

}

So, it does this:

```
.example-class[data-reactid$='first_1']:before {
  content: "second_1";
}

.example-class[data-reactid$='first_1']:before {
  content: "second_2";
}

.example-class[data-reactid$='first_2']:before {
  content: "second_1";
 }

.example-class[data-reactid$='first_2']:before {
  content: "second_2";
}
```

And I want it to just do this:

```
.example-class[data-reactid$='first_1']:before {
  content: "second_1";
}

.example-class[data-reactid$='first_2']:before {
  content: "second_2";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The provided code does not generate the output you're claiming: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7fe14ce08218c952abdc

Comment: ah cool I didn't realize there was a "Sassmiester" tool...

Comment: any thoughts on how to make it work my fellow Sassmiester?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use nested loops, what you want to do is use the zip function to zip your lists together.  The zip function creates a list of lists where the first, second, etc. element of each list is paired up together:

```
$first: first_1 first_2;
$second: second_1 second_2;
@each $k, $v in zip($first, $second) {
    .example-class[data-reactid$='#{$k}'] {
        &:before {
            content: '#{$v}';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.example-class[data-reactid$='first_1']:before {
  content: "second_1";
}

.example-class[data-reactid$='first_2']:before {
  content: "second_2";
}
```

Comment: thanks cinnamon that works great, you are a true sassmiester =)